# Update CSS properties dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, loops

I have the following jQuery code, but it's not changing the color of the negative numbers which is set to colour red in CSS, but in the console, the expected color is corrected.

It's a table where the rows are being created dynamically via AJAX.

Here, my jQuery code, handling data retrieved from a database using AJAX.

```
$.each(data, function (q, z) {
    var rem = z.remaining;
    console.log('rem ' + rem);
    $("#tbody").append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="tick" id="tick"></td><td class="id">' + z.id + '</td><td class="title">' + z.title + '</td><td class="name">' + z.name + '</td><td class="surname">' + z.surname + '<span class="mystyle"> (' + rem + ')</span>' + '</td><td class="sessions"><select name="sessions" id="sessions" class="sesVal"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="4">4</option></select></td><td class="amount"></td></tr>');
    if(rem >= 1) {
        $(".mystyle").css('color','green');
        console.log('green');
    }
    if(rem < 0) {
        $(".mystyle").css('color','red');
        console.log('red');
    }
});
```

Below is a screenshot of the page and browser console;

[image]

Comment: Can we see the HTML related to displaying the tabular data?

Comment: Can you please try with .css(‘color’,’red !important’);

Comment: Just to make your code simpler, you can do `if(rem > = 1) { $(".mystyle").css('color','green'); } else if(rem < 0) { $(".mystyle").css('color','red'); }`  No need to run both if statements everytime.

Comment: cache the content before you add it, run .find on that, then you don't pick up everything else in the dom. `const content = $('all the new html'); $('.myTable').append(content); content.find('.mystyle').css(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of .eq() to apply style to that specific row  , check this eq(index) link for more details - https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

```
$(".mystyle:eq("+q+")")
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pOMBXq

```js
var data = [{
  "remaining":-1,
  "id":1,
  "title":"test",
  "surname":"zzz",
  "name":"yyy"
},{
  "remaining":10,
  "id":2,
  "title":"test2",
  "surname":"zzz2",
  "name":"yyy2"
}]

$.each(data, function (q, z) {
                    var rem = z.remaining;
                    console.log('rem ' + rem, q);
                     $("#tbody").append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="tick" id="tick"></td><td class="id">' + z.id + '</td><td class="title">' + z.title + '</td><td class="name">' + z.name + '</td><td class="surname">' + z.surname + '<span class="mystyle"> (' + rem + ')</span>' + '</td><td class="sessions"><select name="sessions" id="sessions" class="sesVal"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="4">4</option></select></td><td class="amount"></td></tr>');
                    if(rem >= 1) {
                        $(".mystyle:eq("+q+")").css('color','green');
                        console.log('green');
                    }
                     if(rem < 0) {
                        $(".mystyle:eq("+q+")").css('color','red');
                        console.log('red');
                     }
                    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$.each(data, function (q, z) {
  var rem = z.remaining;
  var colorClass = '';
  if(rem >= 1) {
    colorClass = 'green';
  } else if(rem < 0) {
    colorClass = 'red';
  }
  console.log('rem ' + rem);
  $("#tbody").append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="tick" id="tick"></td><td class="id">' + z.id + '</td><td class="title">' + z.title + '</td><td class="name">' + z.name + '</td><td class="surname">' + z.surname + '<span class="' + colorClass + '"> (' + rem + ')</span>' + '</td><td class="sessions"><select name="sessions" id="sessions" class="sesVal"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="4">4</option></select></td><td class="amount"></td></tr>');
});
```

Your newly added CSS:

```
.red { color: red; }
.green { color: green; }
```

Comment: headsup: class is a reserved word, you can't make a variable called 'class'.

Answer (score -1):

class is not unique, meaning more than one element can have the same name. Therefore if you decide to change the color of an element using class name, then all elements with that class name will change color.

```
if(rem >= 1) {
    $(".mystyle").css('color','green');
    console.log('green');
}
if(rem < 0) {
    $(".mystyle").css('color','red');
    console.log('red');
}
```

Here you are telling the code to change all the elements with the class name `mystyle` to green if `rem` greater than 1 or red if it's less than one.

You could add a unique id to it:

```
<span class="mystyle"+rem> (' + rem + ')</span>
if(rem >= 1) {
    $(".mystyle" + rem).css('color','green');
    console.log('green');
}
if(rem < 0) {
    $(".mystyle" + rem).css('color','red');
    console.log('red');
}
```